# What should I test in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

Testing and Rspec are new to me. Currently I'm using Rspec with Shoulda and Capybara to test my application. It's all fine to test models, controllers, helpers, routing and requests. But what should I exactly test in views? Actually I want to test everything in views, including DOM, but I also don't want to overdone things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These three things would be a good starting point

1. Use Capybara to go start at the root of your site, and have it click on links and whatever until it gets to the view you want tested.
2. Make sure what ever content is supposed to be on the page, is actually showing up on the page.  So, if they 'user' went to the **Product 1** page, make sure all the **Product 1** content is actually there.
3. If different users see different content, make sure that's working.  So, if Admin users see Admin-type buttons, make sure the buttons are they when the user is an Admin, and that aren't when the user isn't.

Those 3 things are a pretty good base.  Even the first one is a big win.  That will catch any kind of weird view syntax errors you may have accidentally introduced, as the syntax error will fail the test.

Answer (score 1):

At my work we are using RSpec only to do unit testing.

For business testing or behavior testing we are using Cucumber that is much more readable for the business and IT guys.
It's like a contract that you sign with your business or it's like a documentation that you can execute.

Have a look at Cucumber: http://cukes.info/

Comment: I second cucumber.  I also use capybara along with it.

Comment: Cucumber is an another option that I can use to test views. But what I asked for was "What should I exactly test in views?".

Answer (score 1):

I use view specs to verify that the view uses the IDs and classes I depend on in my jQuery code.

And to test different versions of the same page. E.g.:

I would not want to create two full request or feature specs to check that a new user sees `welcome message A` and a returning user `welcome message B`. Instead I would pick one of the cases, write a request or feature spec for it, and then a additional view spec that tests both cases.

[Rails Test Prescriptions](http://pragprog.com/press_releases/rails-test-prescriptions-keeping-your-application-healthy) might be interesting for you, since it has a chapter dedicated to view testing.